# Consecuence of the existence of isomorphism $\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathfrak{o}(3)$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I have already proved that there exists a vector isomorphism $f$ between $\mathbb{R}^3$ and the set of $3\times 3$-antisymmetric matrix $\mathfrak{o}(3)$, that satisfies  $f(u\times v) =[f(u),f(v)]$ where $\times$ denotes the  vector cross product. I wonder if I can deduce something interesting of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{o}(3)$ from the fact that there is such isomorphism with $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Any idea is welcome.

Comment: What kind of isomorphism? Vector space isomorphism or the stronger Lie-algebra isomorphism?

Comment: Vector space isomorphism. I dont know if it is Lie álgebra iso, but I saw that the same map is lie algebra iso when you consider $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ winstead of $\mathfrak{o}(3)$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107611/canonical-isomorphism-between-mathfrakso3-and-mathbb-r3-with-vector-c see this

Comment: not exactly. what information can I get from the fact that there exists a isomorphism of vector spaces from $\mathbb{R}3$ and $\mathfrak{o}(3)$? that's my question.